# CS50 Finance - can't get quote from form?

Tags: python, flask, cs50

I'm working my way through CS50's finance problem set. (https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/tracks/web/finance/)

In this task a user should be able to submit a form on a html page to request the current price of a share in a company.

Below is what I've made so far for the quote route (using python and flask):

```
@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
"""Get stock quote."""

if request.method == "POST":
    quote = lookup(request.form.get("requested_share"))

    if quote == None:
        return apology("No share found for this symbol")

    return render_template("quoted.html", quote=quote)

# User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
else:
    return render_template("quote.html")
```

And here is what I've written for the "quote" html page:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Quote
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/quote" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="requested_share" placeholder="e.g. TSLA" type="text" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Request Quote</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, here is what I've got for the "quoted" html page (where the user should be taken if their request for a quote is successful):

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Quoted
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<p>A share of {{ quote["name"] }} costs {{ quote["price"] }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

However, when I try it out, it seems to be acting as though the user hasn't typed anything in. Instead of going to the quoted.html page, it goes to the apology page from this part of the code:

```
    if quote == None:
        return apology("No share found for this symbol")
```

Can anyone help with this? I've been staring at it for ages, still can't see where it's going wrong. I thought it might have been something to do with the API Key, though I've followed the instructions on the page

Comment: One quick explanation is that `API_KEY` for IEX is not exported in the environment before `flask run`. And pay close attention to the spec, ie `Require that a user input a stock’s symbol, implemented as a text field whose name is symbol`

Answer (score 0):

I assumed it might have to do with the GET calls returning a None at the end

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://cloud-sse.iexapis.com:443 "GET /stable/stock/AAPL/quote?token=[your_api_key] HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

So, I've tried plugging in your code into mine and swapping out things to make sure I could recreate what you are experiencing:

```
if not quote:
// instead of
if quote == None:
```

It happened once or twice but it turned out to be wrongly entered symbols e.g. 'APPL' instead of 'AAPL' for apple stock.

I had this issue initially when nothing was being returned from the api calls through the lookup() method. If you don't see a message in your console when you lookup a stock symbol like this:

```
"GET /stable/stock/AAPL/quote?token=[your_api_key] HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

or

```
"GET /stable/stock/AAPL/quote?token=[your_api_key] HTTP/1.1" 404 None
```

When GET returns 404 then the *quote == None* triggers and you get the call to the apology() function.

So if you don't see anything similar to thos lines, then that means no calls are being sent to the IEX api. I'm not sure if it's some sorta security feature (or even if that's the case, like someone else commented ensure that your api key is working properly just to be sure) but I tried making the call using the postman app by manually inserting the stock symbol and api key and after that it started working. Postman is an app for building and testing apis, you can get it here - [link to Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

This is what the result looks like in Postman:
[image]

So try that if you haven't and then checking if your console in the CS50 ide is showing the calls being made.